# Combine these SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two queries:

```
--query 1
SELECT Account.*, Opportunity.* FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account
ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId
WHERE YEAR(Opportunity.CreatedOn) = 2016

--query 2
SELECT outbound_number, count(outbound_number) as c
FROM [Telecoms].[dbo].[cdr]
WHERE YEAR(calldate) = 2016 and calltype = 'outgoing' AND Disposition = 'ANSWERED'
GROUP BY outbound_number
```

I'm trying to combine them so for each row in the first one I can also see the count from the second `WHERE Account.Telephone1 = outbound_number`.

What is the right syntax to get this working?

Comment: Is outbound_number a field in Account or in Opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

just do a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT Opportunity.*, Account.*, TotalOutboundCalls=OBN.c
   FROM Opportunity
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Account ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT outbound_number, c=count(outbound_number)
             FROM [Telecoms].[dbo].[cdr]
             WHERE YEAR(calldate) = 2016 
                AND calltype = 'outgoing' 
                AND Disposition = 'ANSWERED'
             GROUP BY outbound_number
       ) OBN ON Account.Telephone1 = OBN.outbound_number
  WHERE YEAR(Opportunity.CreatedOn) = 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT
    Account.*
    ,Opportunity.*
    ,obn.cnt
FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account
    ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT
        COUNT(outbound_number) AS cnt
    FROM [Telecoms].[dbo].[cdr]
    WHERE YEAR(calldate) = 2016
    AND calltype = 'outgoing'
    AND Disposition = 'ANSWERED'
    AND outbound_number = Account.Telephone1
    GROUP BY outbound_number) obn
WHERE YEAR(Opportunity.CreatedOn) = 2016
```

Comment: That would run the second query for EVERY ROW in the original query, right?  feels like it would be long-running if any of those tables has a ton of data).

Comment: @bri - Are you sure that it will run for every row when you have proper index on `[Telecoms].[dbo].[cdr]` table

Comment: "The APPLY operator allows you to join two table expressions; the right table expression is processed every time for each row from the left table expression."

Comment: @bri - Doesn't mean that it will be slow when you have tons of data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done in single query

Try this

```
SELECT account.*, 
       opportunity.*, 
       Count(outbound_number) OVER(partition BY outbound_number) AS outbound_count 
FROM   opportunity 
       LEFT JOIN account 
              ON opportunity.accountid = account.accountid 
       LEFT JOIN [Telecoms].[dbo].[cdr] C
              ON Account.Telephone1 = C.outbound_number
             AND C.calltype = 'outgoing' 
             AND C.disposition = 'ANSWERED'
WHERE  Year(opportunity.createdon) = 2016
```

Comment: This doesn't include the other table (Telecoms.dbo.cdr) in the OP's second query.

Comment: @bri - please refresh the page and check i updated long back

Comment: Have you found this [performance test](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-performance-of-the-t-sql-window-functions/) to be true in reality?  I've always assumed COUNT/OVER is slower than traditional count, but don't have personal experience to prove that out.

Comment: @bri - Good article. I didn't know that, I always thought Window functions are good in performance

Comment: Yeah. It's just some guy on a blog (not my personal experience), so I would call it definitive proof ;-)

Comment: @bri - Good to know. Will definitely test it out

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Account.??, Opportunity.??, count(TDC.outbound_number)
FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account
  ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId
LEFT JOIN [Telecoms].[dbo].[cdr] TDC
  ON TDC.outbound_number = Account.Telephone1
 AND YEAR(TDC.calldate) = 2016 
 AND TDC.calltype = 'outgoing' 
 AND TDC.Disposition = 'ANSWERED'
WHERE YEAR(Opportunity.CreatedOn) = 2016
GROUP BY ??, ??
```

You will need to put something in for the ??.  You won't be able to use the `.*` syntax for grouping. You need to explicitly call out which fields you want to group by.